# Python: What does the two % signs in print '%r k%%k'%'a' do?

Tags: python, quine

I came across this while researching quines. I am curious to know what %% does in the following

`print '%r k%%k'%'a'`

I understand that %r takes the string representation of the argument that's passed (in this case 'a') and adds it to the string with quotes, so in this case it prints 'a' k%k. I can't figure out what k%%k does? If I remove one of the % signs, I get an error. If I have both without the %r, I get an error too. However, when I have both %r and the two % signs in between to ks (or any alphabet), it prints out nearly the same thing, but with one % missing (k%k in this case for k%%k). What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%%` is the escape for a single `%` character; you could not otherwise use that character:

```
>>> '%s: %%' % 'One percent character'
'One percent character: %'
```

See the [*String Formatting Operations* documention](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

> `%`
>   No argument is converted, results in a `'%'` character in the result.

By removing one `%` character, you formed the `%k` format, but there is no conversion type `k`. The error message reflects that:

```
>>> '%k' % 'No such format type'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: unsupported format character 'k' (0x6b) at index 1
```