# How does this Python 3 quine work?

Tags: python, quine

Found this example of quine:

```
s='s=%r;print(s%%s)';print(s%s)
```

I get that `%s` and `%r` do the `str` and `repr` functions, as pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354329/whats-the-meaning-of-r-in-python), but what exactly means the `s%s` part and how the quine works?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`s` is set to:

```
's=%r;print(s%%s)'
```

so the `%r` gets replaced by exactly that (*keeping* the single quotes) in `s%s` and the final `%%` with a single `%`, giving:

```
s='s=%r;print(s%%s)';print(s%s)
```

and hence the quine.

Comment: Specifically, `%r` means use the `repr()` function as opposed to the `str()` function (`%s`). See [`printf`-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

Comment: Thank you! Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255411/python-what-does-the-two-signs-in-print-r-kka-do?rq=1) I found a detailed explanation why s%%s is printed like s%s.

Answer (score 4):

The operator `x % y` means substitute the value `y` in  the format string `x`, same way as C printf. Also note that the `%%` specifier stands for a literal  % sign so `s%%s` within the format string will print as s%s, and will not capture a string.